# p-message(KeyFilterModule) is not a known element in Angular6

Tags: angular, primeng, angular6

When I trying to p-message along with KeyFilterModule from Prime-NG UI Component in Angular 6 and for reference following packages are installed:

> **npm -v**
>   6.1.0

**>ng -v**
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 ia32
Angular: 6.0.9

Please find below code used and throwing the error.

HTML File:

```
      <input type="text" formControlName="UniqueNumber" class="form-control" id="UniqueNumber" name="UniqueNumber" placeholder="Patient Unique Number"
       pInputText [pKeyFilter]="ccRegex" [pValidateOnly]="true" placeholder="123-12-1234" />
       <p-message severity="error" text="Not a valid number" [@errorState]="form.dirty && !form.valid ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"></p-message> 
    </div>
```

ts code:
  ccRegex: RegExp = /[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/;

I understand, KeyFilterModule is newly introduced in Angular 6. Any help in regarding this highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to import messagesmodule, rather I should have used messagemodule.

```
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
import { MessageModule, KeyFilterModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    TableModule,
    MessageModule,
    KeyFilterModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    TableModule,
    MessageModule,
    KeyFilterModule
  ]
})
```

Thanks for the pointer @Lee.Winter! Appreciate your help on the same.

Comment: Yeah after the KeyFilterModule error the MessageModule was the next error I got when using the example for their site

Comment: Sure! Thanks a ton for the response.. Appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. Make sure you import the KeyFilterModule in your app

```
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
import { MessagesModule, KeyFilterModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    TableModule,
    MessagesModule,
    KeyFilterModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    TableModule,
    MessagesModule,
    KeyFilterModule
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should implement it
1. In your component file, add this  import and declare your array

```
import {Message} from 'primeng/components/common/api';
msg: Message[] = [];
```

2. In you ngOninit(), add this

```
this.msg
        .push({
            severity: 'warn',
            summary: 'WarningStatus',
            detail: 'You have not entered all the required data.'
        });
```

3. Add a clear function to remove the banner

```
clear() {
        this.msg = [];
    }
```

4. In your html, add this

```
<p-messages [(value)]="msg" [closable]="false" (onClick)="clear()"></p-messages>
```